# Pagination in codeigniter 3 and send to api

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have following function.

```
public function sendstocktobl()
{
    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== $this->localhost) {
        echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    } else {
        $this->load->database();

        $url = get_integration_url('baselinker');
        $this->db->select('user_id');
        $this->db->where('bl_send_stock', 1);
        $this->db->where('is_baselinker', 1);
        $this->db->where('is_active', 1);
        $resArr = $this->db->get('ci_users')->result_array();

        foreach ($resArr as $row) {

            $user_id = $row['user_id'];

            $limit = 1000;
            $offset = 0;
            $where = "quantity is NOT NULL";
            $this->db->where($where);
            $this->db->where('is_active', 1);
            $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
            $total_results = $this->db->count_all('ci_products');
            $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $limit);

            $token = get_bl_token($user_id);
            $inventoryid = get_bl_inventory($user_id);
            $blwh = get_bl_warehouse($user_id);

            for ($page = 1; $page <= $total_pages; $page++) {

                $arr = [
                    "inventory_id" => $inventoryid,
                    "products" => [],
                ];

                $this->db->select('*');
                $where = "quantity is NOT NULL";
                $this->db->where($where);
                $this->db->where('is_active', 1);
                $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
                $prodArr = $this->db->get('ci_products')->result_array();

                foreach ($prodArr as $prod) {
                    $arr['products'][$prod['id']] =  [$blwh => $prod['quantity']];
                }

                $offset += $limit;
            }
            
            $preparebl = json_encode($arr);
            echo $preparebl;
        }
    }
}
```

Long story short, i need to grab data from sql and send to an api for each users which meets some requirements. I need to prepare apicall like this it's now $arr , but the point it's that pagination it's not working, for user 1 i have 1077 records and i get just one json array with products (1077 products), instead of 2 with maximum 1k .

Could someone help me a bit cause i'm not getting where is the error in my script..

Answer (score 0):

Forgotted to add $limit and offset there:

```
$prodArr = $this->db->get('ci_products')->result_array();
```

Correct:

```
$prodArr = $this->db->get('ci_products', $limit, $offset)->result_array();
```

And added also apicall in "for" loop.

I let here my function which, now it's working fine, maybel it will help someone to inspire.

```
    public function sendstocktobl(){
    if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== $this->localhost) {echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}
    else{
        
        $this->load->database();
        $url = get_integration_url('baselinker');
        $this->db->select('user_id');
        $this->db->where('bl_send_stock',1);
        $this->db->where('is_baselinker',1);
        $this->db->where('is_active',1);
        $resArr = $this->db->get('ci_users')->result_array();

            foreach ($resArr as $row){
        
             $user_id = $row['user_id'];
 
             $limit = 1000;
             $offset = 0;
             $where = "quantity is NOT NULL";

             $total_results = $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id)->where('is_active',1)->where($where)->from("ci_products")->count_all_results();
             $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $limit);

             $token = get_bl_token($user_id);
             $inventoryid = get_bl_inventory($user_id);
             $blwh = get_bl_warehouse($user_id);

             for ($page = 1; $page <= $total_pages; $page++) {

             $arr = [
             "inventory_id" => $inventoryid,
             "products" => [],
             ];

             $this->db->select('*');
             $where = "quantity is NOT NULL";
             $this->db->where($where);
             $this->db->where('is_active',1);
             $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
             $prodArr = $this->db->get('ci_products', $limit, $offset)->result_array();

             foreach($prodArr as $prod){
             $arr['products'][$prod['id']] =  [$blwh => $prod['quantity']];
             }

             $preparebl = json_encode($arr);
             echo $preparebl;
             $offset += $limit;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @M.Eriksson sry for that, i didn't know how to answer on my question. Basically, after i made the post i found the error in my function and i added problem as an answer because i thinked it may help someone else

Comment: Ah, it was a bit unclear that you posted an answer and not just updated the question. I'm not sure how useful this would be for anyone else tbh, since reading the manual would give you the answer.